# Put a border around text inside a div

Tags: css, border

How would I go about putting a border around just the H1 text inside an existing div? The border always goes around the whole div and not just the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to set the H1 to `display: inline-block` or wrap the text in a `span` and apply the border to that.

Eg.

```
<h1><span>Text</span></h1>

/* Css */
h1 {
    padding: 5px;
}
h1 span {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: I used a span. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the fact that any header tags are considered to be block level elements. If you set the H1 tag to "display: inline" this should fix the issue. You may have to set a padding value to adjust the spacing of the border around the H1's text/content.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I set H1 as inline then gave h1 a border- The div has a border; it's not around the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your css:

```
#yourDIVidHere h1{border: solid #ccc}
```

Comment: This puts a border around the div not the text. :(

Answer (score 0):

Html >

`<div><p>Text Here</p></div>`

Css >

`div p {
border: 1px solid #000;
}`